# how to link the 'PATCH' and 'PUT' methods to my 'API' in order to use them?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I made a PHP REST API that allows a user to register, connect, modify their information and delete them. I was able to link the 'register' and 'login' part to my frontend vue. But the problem is that I can't link 'PATCH' or 'PUT' to my frontend to allow a user to modify his information. Here is my backend code for the 'update':

```
<?php
// Les entêtes requises
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-type: application/json; charset= UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PATCH");

require_once '../config/Database.php';
require_once '../models/User.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "PATCH") {
    // On instancie la base de données
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnexion();

    // On instancie l'objet user
    $user = new User($db);

    // On récupère les infos envoyées
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    if (!empty($data->id) && !empty($data->Nom) && !empty($data->Prenom) && !empty($data->email)) {
        // On hydrate l'objet user
        $user->id = intval($data->id);
        $user->Nom = htmlspecialchars($data->Nom);
        $user->Prenom = htmlspecialchars($data->Prenom);
        $user->email = htmlspecialchars($data->email);
        

        $result = $user->update();
        if ($result) {
            http_response_code(201);
            echo json_encode(['message' => "L'utilisateur a été modifié avec sucès"]);
        } else {
            http_response_code(503);
            echo json_encode(['message' => "La modification de l'utilisateur a échoué"]);
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['message' => "Les données ne sont pas au complet"]);
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(405);
    echo json_encode(['message' => "La méthode n'est pas autorisée"]);
}
```

```
Et ensuite, voici le code de mon frontend:
```

```
import axios from "axios";
  
  export default {
    name: "UpdateProfile",
    data() {
      return {
        user:{},
        form: {
        Nom: "",
        Prenom: "",
        email: "",
      },
      showError: false
      };
    },
methods: {
      async submit(id) {
      try {
        await axios
        .patch("{http://localhost/PHP-API-REST/controllers/update.php}/{id}", {
             submit: true
        });
        this.$router.push("/profile");
        this.showError = false
      } catch (error) {
        this.showError = true;
        console.error(error);
      }
    }, 
 }
```

But it does not work. how to do? I am a beginner. With what I've done, I'm still getting a '404 page not found' error. However I tried with postman and it works, but when I try with my frontend, I have problems. Your answers will be welcome.